# Regex: match only when a substring is present between two words

Tags: regex

I want to limit the search between 2 words.

I have tried:

```
<Notes>(?:(?!<Notes>)[\s\S])*?sample(?:[\s\S\w]+)<\/Notes>(?:(?<![\s\S\w]<\/Notes>))*?
```

with options `/gmU`

For Text:

```
TextBefore<Notes>this is sample notes</Notes>TextWiths1ample<Notes>this is sample notes</Notes>
```

and Text:

```
TextBefore<Notes>this is sample notes</Notes>TextWithsample<Notes>this is sample notes</Notes>
```

The screenshot below will give you an idea of what I want to achieve:
[succesfull](https://i.stack.imgur.com/do1m5.png).

But the screenshot below shows that the regex is not limited between the 2 words: [failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cn9qW.png)

Hope someone can help me (there is a reason why not to parse this as XML).

Saved regexp: https://regex101.com/r/0fhNxI/1

Comment: Hi Wiktor, i have edited the question and put some more information in it. Hope you can help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, remove the `U` flag, it is very confusing since it swaps lazy and greedy quantifiers. Then, make sure you exclude both `<Notes>` and `</Notes>` from matching before `sample`. It is also a good idea to exclude the `sample`, too, and use

```
<Notes>(?:(?!<\/?Notes>|sample)[\s\S])*sample[\s\S]*?<\/Notes>
```

Or,

```
<Notes>(?:(?!<\/?Notes>)[\s\S])*?sample[\s\S]*?<\/Notes>
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/WUgUMI/3) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/WUgUMI/2).

Note that `[\s\S\w]` = `[\s\S]`.

*Details*:

- `<Notes>` - a fixed string
- `(?:(?!<\/?Notes>)[\s\S])*?` - any char, zero or more occurrences (as few as possible), that does not start a `<Notes>` or `</Notes>` char sequence
- `sample` - a fixed string
- `[\s\S]*?` - any zero or more chars as few as possible
- `<\/Notes>` - a fixed string.

Comment: Hi Wiktor, thank you very much for the working solution and the very fast response.